# Ignoring DEFAULT constraints when comparing in Aqua data studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, compare, database-schema

I have to compare two SQL server 2012's schemas with Aqua Data Studio 6.5.9

The two schemas have more or less the same tables, most differences are between DEFAULT constraints, which are different because auto-generated by SQL Server.
[image: comparison results]
Is there a way to ignore DEFAULT constraints names?

Comment: I don't know about Aqua but redgate tool has filter options. May be you will find something like this in Aqua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Aqua Data Studio v14, a new option is introduced which can take care of auto-generated constraint names. You can disable this checkbox and the schema compare tool will ignore the differences. This feature is however not possible in ADS v6.5.9

[image]
Uncheck that option and now you can compare the Tables and will show the differences correctly.

[image]